# Can I use MVP design pattern inside TabLayout Fragment, if yes how to do this?

Tags: java, android

Inside my app I use TabLayout and I want each TabLayout Fragment handle by MVP. Please answer how to use MVP...

Thanx...

Comment: check this link :https://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make each fragment implement a common interface, which the presenter class will use it.  This will allow the presenter to be decoupled with the fragment.

2) On your presenter's constructor, pass an object of your fragment.  In your presenter you will do all the logic.  Whenever you create an object of your presenter on your fragment you will pass that object.

3) Use the presenter object in the view(fragment) to trigger an action on your presenter. The presenter will be listening to that trigger and perform some logic, once completed the presenter will use the object of the interface to invoke the implemented method from the fragment.

In summary, your fragment and xml will represent the view, the model will be the POJO, the presenter will be a controller which performs some logic when an action occurs in your fragment.  Your presenter will not be tied to any fragment since your presenter will work with an object of the fragment/activity which implemented the interface.

Reference: https://academy.realm.io/posts/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/